# Postgres replication stop

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-12, wal, logical-replication

My replication suddenly stopped, data are not replicated to the subscriber. I don't really know the cause may be because of ID conflict.

I try a couple of things, but none work :

```
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION test_mysub REFRESH publication;
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION test_mysub ENABLE;
```

*(Note: `ALTER SUBSCRIPTION test_mysub REFRESH publication` works when there are columns difference between publisher and subscriber.)*

The subscriber has 2000 less records than the publisher. Seems that there are some WALs not sent to the subscriber. Then I deleted all records in the subscriber, and automatically that 2000 records are inserted and the replication works again.

Addendum:
I know what causing the problem : ID conflict.

Here is what I do to replicate the problem :

1. Insert a record with an ID 1000 on the Subscriber
2. Insert a record with an ID 1000 on the Publisher
3. Check the Publisher : `select * from pg_stat_replication;`. The result is NULL. Its is an indication that the subscription stopped.
4. Insert a record with an ID 1001 on the Publisher

After that I check the Subscriber, ID 1001 does not present.

How I recover :

1. Delete the record with ID 1000 on the Subscriber
2. Check the Publisher : `select * from pg_stat_replication;`. There is a record, with State column = streaming.
3. Check the Subscriber. There are 2 new record : ID 1000 and 1001, both from publisher.

It seems that the replication works again if I remove the causing record. After that, the replication works again automatically without having to be restarted.

Questions :

1. How can I entry the records that are not sent (the 2000 records) from the publisher without deleting the duplicating ID existing on the subscriber ?
2. I am wondering If I can see the records on the failed WAL files and be able to delete the causing ID in the WAL. Is it possible ? Or is there any better solution ?

Thanks